# How to send special character like å in header from okhttp library

Tags: android, okhttp

Is it possible to send special characters in headers from okhttp library? Right now my app crashes showing the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0xe5 at 1 in username value: påfyll
                                                   at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.checkNameAndValue(Headers.java:320)
```

This is how i am sending the request.

```
okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url(AppConfig.CONCERT_LIST)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            .addHeader("username", "påfulo")
            .addHeader("accessToken", "12345ASDFGsf98")
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple, you will have to encode it and have your server to decode it.

You can find more information about this problem here :
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2016

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it **ASCII** char rather then string.On the server you can get original value from it.
You can find your **ASCII** character down here-:

**http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html**